# I am trying to access user location with key, "location.address.formatted",

Tags: google-plus, google-apis-explorer

I am using google API console to check google+ API, i am trying to assess user formatted address to store in my database at the time user signup.

Comment: What is your question? Please spend time to create your question with relevant details, code, expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ API has been shut down.